# What exactly does "Uniqueness of inverse matrix" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been trouble understanding the description: “Uniqueness of the inverse matrix”.

Or, more specifically, what exactly the term *"Unique"* here means? An explanation of the proof of this claim would also be appreciated and help with my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ and $B$ both be inverses of $A$:

$$B = BI = B(AC) =(BA)C = IC = C$$

Where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Unique means that there is one and only one, in other words take $C,B$ inverses of $A, C$ and $B$ must be equal they cannot be distinct, as shown in the proof.

Comment: Unique means that there is one and only one, in other words take C,B inverses of A, C and B must be equal they cannot be distinct, as shown in the proof.

Comment: Why is this a comment and not part of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

An inverse of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix $B$ such that $BA=I_n$ and $AB=I_n$.

To say that $A$ has unique inverse means: if $B$ is an inverse of $A$, and $B'$ is an inverse of $A$, then $B=B'$. In other words, if $B$ has the property that $AB=BA=I_n$, and $B'$ has the property that $B'A=AB'=I_n$, then $B$ and $B'$ must be the same matrix.

It can be shown that if a square matrix has an inverse, then this inverse must be unique. The proof is simple, but perhaps not obvious: if $B$ and $B'$ are inverses of $A$, then
$$
B=BI=B(AB')=(BA)B'=IB'=B' \, ,
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix of the same dimension as $A$.

If you are familiar with some abstract algebra, then it is worthwhile to note that the set of invertible $n\times n$ matrices with entries in a field $K$ form a group under multiplication, known as the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) $GL_n(K)$. The proof of uniqueness of inverses given above is just the proof that inverses are unique in any group, specialised to the case of $GL_n(K)$.

A more difficult result to prove is that if $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, and it is known that $BA=I_n$, then $A$ is invertible, and $B$ is its inverse.